# Access Dynamic Parameters EmberJS

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

I want to update a view once a user is logged. Getting his profile picture, name, etc from a server and use that information to refresh the view. And I don't want to change the route I'm in.

The way I'm handling the logging in is by using a boolean variable `isLoggedIn`. I change it's value to `true` once the user is logged in. I have a binding listening for changes on that variable which then executes a update to the actual route's model with the user info.

```
App.TripsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
 isLoggedInBinding: 'App.Session.isLoggedIn'

 isLoggedInChanged: (->
   @model()
 ).observes('isLoggedIn')

 model: ->
   App.Trip.find()
```

So the question is : Is there any way to access the dynamic parameters from inside a route's custom method to update the related model?

**Note**: I don't want to do this inside the route's model hook, because it is only executed when entered via URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can store a reference to the current user in `App` and access that to determine if a user is logged in and use the details to update the current view.

Store the `currentUser`:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  currentUser: null
});
```

This can then be get/set anywhere in your app using `App.get('currentUser')` or `App.set('currentUser', newUser)`.

In your template you can check if the user is logged in or not and automatically display their information if they are logged in:

```
  {{#if App.currentUser }}
    <img {{bindAttr src='App.currentUser.avatarURL'}} /> </br>
    Logged in as: {{App.currentUser.name}}
  {{else}}
    Not logged in.
  {{/if}}
```

Once you update the `App.currentUser` with the current user's user object Ember's data bindings will update your view will automatically with the profile information.

[Example in JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ihotef/3/edit)